# How to handle Button's multiple ControlEvents in single method?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have one button,

On button touch i have to handle **multiple control event[Like, UITouchupinside,UITouchupoutside,etc]** to fire different actions according to event.

Currently i am handling this using different methods. like below

```
- (IBAction)holdDown:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Hold down");
}
- (IBAction)released:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@“Touch up inside”);
}
- (IBAction)touchUpOutside:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"touchUpOutside");
}
```

But i don’t want to call different methods for different Events. Can i use **single method** to handle all **control events**.
like

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
     // here i want to identify which control event it is
    nslog( @"touchupinside"); //When fier call this
    nslog( @"touchupoutside"); // When fier call this

}
```

The above requirement is working fine with above methods. But i want to identify the different controlEvents like TouchUpInside,TouchUpOutside and TouchDown ect.... in single method
 `- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender)`.

Comment: I agree i forget that

Comment: please check edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Easy way,

Just set tag to your buttons ,

And select one action for all the the button check in below image,

[image]

And access all the button with tag,

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender {

    if (sender.tag==1) {
        NSLog(@"button 1");
    }
  else  if (sender.tag==2) {
      NSLog(@"button 2");
    }
   else if (sender.tag==3) {
       NSLog(@"button 3");
    }
}
```

**Edit 1 :- If you want to access all event state in one method then you can access with** **UIControllallevent**.

Check below code:-

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender {

    if (sender.tag==1) {
        NSLog(@"button 1");
         if (sender.allControlEvents)
        {
            if (sender.allControlEvents==UIControlEventTouchUpInside) {
                NSLog(@"Touchup inside");
            }
            else if (sender.allControlEvents==UIControlEventTouchUpOutside)
            {
                NSLog(@"Touchup Uoutside");
            }
            else if (sender.allControlEvents==UIControlEventValueChanged)
            {
                NSLog(@"EventValueChanged");

            }
            else if (sender.allControlEvents==UIControlEventTouchDragInside)
            {
                NSLog(@"TouchDragInside");

            }



        }

    }
  else  if (sender.tag==2) {
      NSLog(@"button 2");
    }
   else if (sender.tag==3) {
       NSLog(@"button 3");
    }
}
```

You will access all the event this way.

[image]
I hope this information is helpful for you

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate ? Even means you want to check event state for 3 button in 1 action ?

Comment: NO i have one button only. i have to handle that button different events in one method

Comment: @ReddyBasha ok got it yor problem. please check edited answer.

Comment: @ReddyBasha your question is valuable but you didn't explain it clearly. i have edited your question. please check it.  and if you need any editing then add it.

Comment: Sha Thanks for editing the question. i am implementing your suggestions, I will let you know once i done.

Comment: @ReddyBasha please mark as right if it works for you.

Comment: actually it is not working for me. I am debugging that, i will let you know what is problem

Comment: it is entering into if (sender.allControlEvents) this condition. But fails to enter  next if conditions like if (sender.allControlEvents==UIControlEventTouchUpInside). Do you have any idea what is the problem or am i missing something

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a method that accepts the button as well as the event as below:

```
- (IBAction)newMethod:(UIButton *)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

UIButton actions pass you the parameters depending upon method signature. Use the event to find out which event has triggered the method. Add this method as target selector to your button as

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(newMethod:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside|UIControlEventTouchUpOutside|UIControlEventTouchDown]
```

From IB you need to drag and connect to this method for each of the event you want to connect.

Comment: How to use your suggested method?. I tried but no luck

Comment: I think you can use it as `[button addTarget:self action:@selector(newMethod:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]`. You can also just drag and select the method if your button is in IB.

Comment: Than that method only respond on touchUpInside right. what i have to do if i want to identify different events on same method like (TouchUpOutSide).

Comment: I am connecting through IB like how you said. But no luck. Have you tried to connect from IB and identifying the control events

Comment: Create the method in .m file and from the button in IB pull string from each of the events and connect it to the same method. It would work.

Answer (score -1):

Define Only one method and in Sent Event pass same method (ctrl+drag) in all event that u can call the method.

Answer (score -2):

You can ctrl+drag multiple actions to the same method and in that method you can check what type of event you received and do actions accordingly.